# Flutter Text Form Field Phone Number Mask

Tags: flutter

I want to print the phone number written in the text form field like this;

```
xxxx-xxx-xxxx
```

but I want to do this without using any packages.
Can you help me?

Comment: What code you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with the InputTextFormatter

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final _mobileFormatter = PhoneNumberTextInputFormatter();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      maxLength: 13,
      inputFormatters:[
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
        _mobileFormatter,
      ],
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        icon: Icon(Icons.phone_iphone),
        hintText: "Mobile*",
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PhoneNumberTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    final int newTextLength = newValue.text.length;
    int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;
    int usedSubstringIndex = 0;
    final StringBuffer newText = new StringBuffer();
    if (newTextLength >= 5) {
      newText.write(newValue.text.substring(0, usedSubstringIndex = 4) +'-' );
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 5)
        selectionIndex += 3;
    }
    if (newTextLength >= 7) {
      newText.write(newValue.text.substring(4, usedSubstringIndex = 7) );
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 7)
        selectionIndex++;
    }
    if (newTextLength >= 8) {
      newText.write('-'+newValue.text.substring(7, usedSubstringIndex = 8) );
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 11)
        selectionIndex++;
    }
    if (newTextLength >= usedSubstringIndex)
      newText.write(newValue.text.substring(usedSubstringIndex));
    return new TextEditingValue(
      text: newText.toString(),
      selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newText.length),
    );
  }
}
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score -7):

You can use the obscureText: true parameter like this:

```
            const Form(
          child: TextField(
            obscureText: true,
          ),
        ),
```

There is a video for this:
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0V5mXbUM_k0)

Comment: Masking and obscure are different because masking is used to format the input and obscure is used to hide the input as you type.